# Docker Swarm - equivalent docker commands

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

As far as I know, the Docker Swarm API is compatible with the Offical Docker API.

What is the equivalent Docker Swarm commands for the following docker commands:

1. `docker ps -a`
2. `docker run --net=host --privileged=true \`

   `-e DEVICE=$VETH_NAME -e SWARM_MANAGER_ADDR=$SWARM_MANAGER_ADDR -e SWARM_MANAGER_PORT=$SWARM_MANAGER_PORT \`

   `-v conf_files:/etc/sur \`

   `-v conf_files:/etc/sur/rules \`

   `-v _log:/var/log/sur\`

   `-d sur`

Comment: Which version of Swarm? The original container based Swarm or the newer Swarmkit based, or if you don't know that, how did you create your Swarm?

Comment: Hey,

I'm about to set up the one that is specified here: https://github.com/docker/swarm

Thanks,
Efrat

Answer (score 1):

The standalone swarm simply has a different host/port for you to connect with the client (client being the `docker` cli). It relays the commands as appropriate from the manager to each node in the swarm. The easiest way to do that is to set `$DOCKER_HOST` to point to the port the manager is listening to:

```
# start your manager, the end of the command is your discovery method
docker run -d -P --restart=always --name swarm-manager swarm manager ...

# send all future commands to the manager
export DOCKER_HOST=$(docker port swarm-manager 2375)

# run any docker ps, docker run, etc commands on the Swarm
docker ps
docker run --net=host --privileged=true \
  -e DEVICE=$VETH_NAME \
  -e SWARM_MANAGER_ADDR=$SWARM_MANAGER_ADDR \
  -e SWARM_MANAGER_PORT=$SWARM_MANAGER_PORT \
  -v conf_files:/etc/sur \
  -v conf_files:/etc/sur/rules \
  -v _log:/var/log/sur \
  -d sur

# return to running commands on the local docker host
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

If you needed those SWARM_MANAGER_ADDR/PORT values defined, those can come out of the `docker port` command. Otherwise, I'm not familiar with the "sur" image to know about the values you need to pass there.

Comment: Thanks!!
Do you know if it's possible to define kind of a Swarm rule saying that "if a container A has been created and ran, create container B" ?

Comment: Not specifically with Swarm. You can create constraints with the filters to ask for containers to run only on machines where another specific container is running. But more likely, you want docker-compose which is used to deploy a group of containers together with your selected options.

Comment: @EfratLevy replying into your comment, you can look into docker compose files written in .yml format to give necessary configurations and define constraints as well. Look into this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/